If $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $\eta\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $u\eta\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$
This is Exercise 11.27 (Page 326) of A first course in Sobolev spaces, second edition. Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set, let $1\leqslant p\leqslant \infty$, $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $\eta\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (i.e. $\eta$ is a smooth function with compact support on $\mathbb{R}^n$).
My question is, why $u\eta\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

I am sure that if $\eta\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, then $u\eta\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Now $\eta\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which means the support of $\eta$ may not be contained in $\Omega$ (i.e. $\mathrm{supp}\ \eta\not\subset \Omega$). I am not very sure whether $\mathrm{supp}\ \eta\not\subset \Omega$ may cause problems at the boundary of $\Omega$.

The fact that $\mathrm{supp} \eta \not \subset \Omega$ does not cause any problems here because $\eta$ is still a very nice function.
First of all, being smooth with compact support in $\mathbb R^n$ implies that $\eta$ and all its derivatives are bounded. Therefore
$$||u \eta||_{L^p(\Omega)} \le ||\eta||_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}||u||_{L^p(\Omega)} <\infty$$
which means that $u \eta \in L^p(\Omega)$. For the derivatives we first check that the weak $i$-th derivative is given by $u \partial_i \eta + \eta \partial_i u$. This can be checked by the integration by parts formula: Let $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ (this time truly with support in $\Omega$). Then we need to show that
$$\int_\Omega (u\eta) \partial_i \varphi dx =-\int_\Omega (u \partial_i \eta + \eta \partial_i u) \varphi dx$$
However, note that $\eta \varphi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ as a product of smooth functions and because one of them has support in $\Omega$. Therefore, by the integration by parts formula for the weak derivative $\partial_i u$ (which we know to exist because $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$) we have:
$$\int_\Omega (\partial_i u) (\eta\varphi) dx = -\int_\Omega u(\eta \partial_i \varphi + \varphi \partial_i \eta) dx$$
which after rearranging is exactly what we wanted.
It remains to show that the weak derivative is in $L^p(\Omega)$. There again we use that $\eta$ and all derivatives are bounded:
$$||u \partial_i \eta + \eta \partial_i u||_{L^p(\Omega)} \le ||\partial_i \eta||_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)} ||u||_{L^p(\Omega)} + ||\eta||_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)} ||\partial_i u||_{L^p(\Omega)} \le C(\eta) ||u||_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}<\infty.$$
Therefore $u\eta \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.
In essence what we needed here was that $\eta, \partial_i \eta$ are bounded for $i=1, \dots, n$; the support of $\eta$ doesn't matter at all. On top of that in order to have $\eta \varphi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ we needed $\eta$ to be smooth (all derivatives exist and are smooth). But it would not be a problem if $\eta$ didn't have compact support as long as the function and all first derivatives are bounded.

It is very helpful. Thank you!
